# How to set Progress bar on Message Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

I want to set progress bar on my message box how to set ...progress bar property style have Marquee property.....
Message box code is bellow.......

```
  MessageBox.Show("Data process please wait .", "Data progress ", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Suggest you tag your question at least with the programming language so that it reaches the right people.

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to do that using MessageBox.  You need to implement your own Form which would look like a MessageBox, but contain a progress bar and/or anything else which you want to see there.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write custom Message box

Comment: Derive from Form, place a Label and a ProgressBar on it. When you need only OK/Cancel place the Buttons, too - if you need dynamic button combinations it gets more complicated. In the ButtonClicked events set the DialogResult property ...

Comment: You can set the dialogresult directly on the button. so 'ok' has DialogResult.OK and 'cancel' has DialogResult.Cancel. The Propery you have to set is 'DialogResult' and you can set it using the Properties-Windows for the button.

Comment: Yes, you are right - and you even get the standard behaviour - ESC = close, Enter = Ok ...

Comment: Yes, what tanascius said: derive from Form, add your controls, etc.

Comment: Thanks crauscher, I didn't realize this!!  For others, its specifically, Properties/Behavior/DialogResult.